# Cara con movimiento por consola en C#

Tags: c#, funciones, loops, consola

tengo un problema al ejecutar una función en consola, quiero hacer que una cara se mueva de derecha a izquierda pero el movimiento no se ejecuta cuando le añado la función de los ojos, fue mi lógica poner dos funciones apartes y no sólo en una.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 1; i < 60; i++)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                dibujarRectangulo(9, 6, i, 1);
                dibujarOjos(i + 1, 2);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                Console.ForegroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
                i -= 1;
                dibujarRectangulo(9, 6, i, 1);
            }
            for (i = 60; i > 5; i--)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                dibujarRectangulo(9, 6, i, 1);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                Console.ForegroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
                dibujarRectangulo(9, 6, i, 1);
            }
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

        static void dibujarRectangulo(int ancho, int alto, int x, int y)
        {
            int cont = 0;
            while (cont < ancho)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x + cont, y);
                Console.Write("-");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x + cont, y + alto);
                Console.Write("-");
                cont++;
            }
            cont = 0;
            while(cont < alto)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y + cont);
                Console.Write("|");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x + ancho, y + cont);
                Console.Write("|");
                cont++;
            }
        }

        static void dibujarOjos(int x, int y)
        {

            while (true)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(3, 2);
                Console.Write("■");
            }

        }
```

Como ven, el gráfico no se mueve cuando le añado la función de **dibujarOjos**, que problema tengo?, de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es que si pones un while (true) en esa función entra el bucle infinito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El principal problema es el `while(true)` que tienes en el método `DibuarOjos` que hace que entre en un bucle infinito.

Por otro lado estás dibujando un único ojo y siempre en la misma posición.

También tienes un `i -= 1;` en el primer bucle que hace que se convierta en otro bucle infinito con la variable `i` siempre teniendo el mismo valor.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < 60; i++)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            dibujarRectangulo(9, 6, i, 1);
            dibujarOjos(i + 3, 2);
            dibujarOjos(i + 6, 2);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.ForegroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
            dibujarRectangulo(9, 6, i, 1);
            dibujarOjos(i + 3, 2);
            dibujarOjos(i + 6, 2);
        }
        for (i = 60; i > 5; i--)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            dibujarRectangulo(9, 6, i, 1);
            dibujarOjos(i + 3, 2);
            dibujarOjos(i + 6, 2);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.ForegroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
            dibujarRectangulo(9, 6, i, 1);
            dibujarOjos(i + 3, 2);
            dibujarOjos(i + 6, 2);
        }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}

static void dibujarRectangulo(int ancho, int alto, int x, int y)
{
    int cont = 0;
    while (cont < ancho)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + cont, y);
        Console.Write("-");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + cont, y + alto);
        Console.Write("-");
        cont++;
    }
    cont = 0;
    while (cont < alto)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y + cont);
        Console.Write("|");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + ancho, y + cont);
        Console.Write("|");
        cont++;
    }
}

static void dibujarOjos(int x, int y)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
    Console.Write("■");
}
```